# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:30.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-appcompat, androidx

I am beginner and getting this error in Android Studio :-

> Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:30.0.0
>   Install Repository and sync project
> Show in File
> Show in Project Structure dialog

And here is my gradle code :-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.piyushbairagi.demoapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:30.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I am using Android Studio 2.2.1 version for learning purpose. Any help will really be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It happens because the support libraries `v.30` **don't** exist.

Use the **androidx** library:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
```

or use the last support library:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

Comment: I've not migrating to AndroidX, so I've got problem with: ```'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'```but succeeded with ```implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'```

Answer (score 7):

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

You can add these to the gradle.properties file and this shall work fine. I had the same issue and adding these removed the error. Also try updating  all the plugins and components of the Android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Latest version available for Support Libraries is `28.0.0`.

So, you must update your `build.gradle` as follows:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

Support library was discontinued. So, don't expect any new release after `28.0.0`.

Google is now supporting AndroidX. In a certain (and basic) way, is the same thing. So, you may want to consider to migrate your app to Android X in order to get support from Google.

More info about Android X:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Answer (score 0):

This error is probably due to the fact that you do not have the updated Gradle and sdk installed in Android Studio.
You must be install updated version of those or change targetsdk version and sdk version and compile appcompact to The version of you installed in pc as picture.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xnpf.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

Generally, the problem is about your sdk version just check it may correspond to your dependencies version 27.+ or 26.0 etc ....

Just check the version of your sdk it may correspond to the needed version for your app like in this picture

[image]

[image]